# Parsing XMl with unknown tag names in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse xml to a stringbuilder in C#. But the XML file has un-determined tag names inside. I don't want to put element names by using `xdoc.elements("tagName")`. I wish I can dynamically loop through the XML file.

The XML I have is like this:

```
 <userInfo>
        <name> Gummy Bear </name>
        <age> 1 </age>
 </userInfo>

 <userInfo>
        <name> Dorito </name>
        <Email> IloveDorito@gmail.com </email>
        <hobby> eating Doritos </hobby>
 </userInfo>
```

As you have seen in the sample file, the only tag in common for each user is `<userInfo>`

**The ideal output would be grouped by each user:**

`Gummy Bear`, `1`,

`Dorito`,`IloveDorito@gmail.com`,`eating Doritos`

I have the following code but it combines all the elements under one user into one line.

```
 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");
 var userNode = xdoc.Root.Elements("userInfo");
 foreach(var d in userNode)
 {
        result.append(d.value):
 }
MessageBox.show (result+"");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest change from your code would be a basic nested loop:

```
foreach(var userInfo in xdoc.Root.Elements("userInfo"))
{
    var details = userInfo.Elements();
    if (details.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach(var detail in details)
        {
            result.Append(detail.Value.Trim() + ", ");
        }
        result.Remove(result.Length - 2, 2).Append("\n");
    }
}
```

LINQ to XML (i.e. `XDocument` and related types) do support a more powerful approach, as the other answers show.

Answer (score 2):

```
var userInfos = XDocument.Load(filename)
        .Descendants("userInfo")
        .Select(d => d.Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => (string)e))
        .ToList();



foreach (var ui in userInfos)
{
    foreach (var item in ui)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " > " + item.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here how you can get what you need

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            var userInfos = XElement.Load("file.xml").Descendants("userInfo").Select(elt =>
            {
                var  line = elt.Descendants();
                return  string.Join(",", line.Select(subElt => subElt.Value)); 
            });
            foreach (var userInfo in userInfos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
            }
Console.ReadLine();  


        }
```

//I suppose you have an XML file like this

```
<root>
<userInfo>
  <name> Gummy Bear </name>
  <age> 1 </age>
</userInfo>

<userInfo>
  <name> Dorito </name>
  <email>IloveDorito@gmail.com </email>
    <hobby> eating Doritos </hobby>
 </userInfo>
</root>
```

**Output**

[image]